# Read a Django UploadedFile into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: django, pandas

I am attempting to read a .csv file uploaded to Django into a DataFrame.

I am following the instructions and the Django REST Framework page for [uploading files](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser). When I `PUT` a .csv file to a defined endpoint I end up with a Django [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files) object, in particular, a `TemporaryUploadedFile`.

I am trying to read this object into a pandas Dataframe using `read_csv`, however, there is additional formatting around the temporary uploaded file. I am wondering how to read the original .csv file that was uploaded.

According to the DRF docs, I have assigned:

```
file_obj = request.data['file']
```

Inside of a Python debugging console, I see:

```
ipdb> file_obj                                                                                                                                                                            
<TemporaryUploadedFile: foobar.csv (multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------044608164241682586561733)>
```

**Things I've tried so far.**

With the original file path, I can read it into pandas like this.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(open("foobar.csv", "rb"))
```

However, the original file has additional metadata added by Django during the upload process.

```
ipdb> pd.read_csv(open(file_obj.temporary_file_path(), "rb"))                                                                                                                             
*** pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 32
```

If I try to use the `UploadedFile.read()` method, I run into the following issue.

```
ipdb> dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_obj.read())                                                                                                                                            
*** OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

Thanks!

P.S. The first few lines of the original file look like this.

```
SPID,SA_ID,UOM,DIR,DATE,RS,NAICS,APCT,1:00,2:00,3:00,4:00,5:00,6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,18:00,19:00,20:00,21:00,22:00,23:00,0:00:00
(Blanked),123456789,KWH,R,5/2/18,H2ETOUAN,,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.144,1.064,3.07,4.531,4.013,5.205,4.751,4.647,3.142,2.464,1.173,0.023,0,0,0,0,0
(Blanked),123456789,KWH,R,3/10/18,H2ETOUAN,,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.007,0.622,0.179,0.003,0.274,0.167,0.014,0.004,0.028,0.139,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

When I look at the contents of the temporary file, I see this.

```
----------------------------789873173211443224653494
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foobar.csv"
Content-Type: File

SPID,SA_ID,UOM,DIR,DATE,RS,NAICS,APCT,1:00,2:00,3:00,4:00,5:00,6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,18:00,19:00,20:00,21:00,22:00,23:00,0:00:00
(Blanked),123456789,KWH,R,5/2/18,H2ETOUAN,,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.144,1.064,3.07,4.531,4.013,5.205,4.751,4.647,3.142,2.464,1.173,0.023,0,0,0,0,0
(Blanked),123456789,KWH,R,3/10/18,H2ETOUAN,,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.007,0.622,0.179,0.003,0.274,0.167,0.014,0.004,0.028,0.139,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: can you show first few rows of your csv from text editor? I think you need to specify the delimitor or do some preprocessing prior to using pandas - also no need for `open()` just do `pd.read_csv(args)`

Comment: Yes, I added the first few rows of the original file as well as what the file looks like in its temporary location. I am unsure if that header will remain consistent for all uploads.

Answer (score 15):

`UploadedFile.read()` returns the file data in bytes, not a file path or file-like object. In order to use pandas `read_csv()` function, you'll need to turn those bytes into a stream. Since your file is a csv, the most straightforward way would be to use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) with [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o), like:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_obj.read().decode('utf-8')), delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This works when there are no headers/footers. I asked the question again in a more focused way to address storing the uploaded files minus the headers/footers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182806/post-a-file-to-django-rest-framework-without-headers-footers

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, an alternative to @chemicollins's answer is to wrap the bytes in a file-like object using `io.BytesIO` and pass that off to `read_csv`.

```py
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file_obj.read()))
```

With that being said, if the csv is in a non utf-8 encoding, then decoding the bytes and using `io.StringIO` is probably warranted. For example:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_obj.read().decode('utf-16')))
```

---

To answer the contents of the question of skipping the meta data at the top of the csv, one way is to read the first few lines of the csv using a delimiter you know is not correct (which forces each line to be in a single column), determine how many rows to skip and read the file again by passing the rows.

An example:

```py
# read first 10 rows using an invalid delimiter
tmp = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|', header=None, nrows=10)
# determine rows to skip
skiprows = next(index for index, value in tmp[0].items() if not value.startswith('Content') and not value.startswith('---'))
# read the csv by skipping the metadata
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', skiprows=skiprows)
```

With that being said, it's probably too late for OP but judging by what `file_obj` is and what the header says, this csv is part of a multi-part request, so using an appropriate parser like `MultiPartParser` etc. probably solves the issue entirely.