# Post a file to Django REST Framework without Headers/Footers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to store a .csv file uploaded to Django REST Framework in its original format.

I am following the instructions and the Django REST Framework page for [uploading files](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser). When I `PUT` a .csv file to a defined endpoint I end up waith a file with additional headers and footers. I am trying to save this file into a `FileField` in its original format so I can run some post-processing steps more easily.

**Steps I've taken:**

I created a model to store the file.

```
from django.db import models


class OriginFile(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="origin_files/")
```

And I created an `APIView` to handle the upload.

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework.response import Response

from reference.reference_model.models import OriginFile


class OriginFileView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        f = request.data["file"]
        load_origin_file = OriginFile()
        load_origin_file.file.save(filename, f, save=True)
        return Response(status=204)
```

**What I am seeing:**

The first couple of lines of my original file look like:

```
SPID,SA_ID,UOM,DIR,DATE,RS,NAICS,APCT,0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15,1:30,1:45,2:00,2:15,2:30,2:45,3:00,3:15,3:30,3:45,4:00,4:15,4:30,4:45,5:00,5:15,5:30,5:45,6:00,6:15,6:30,6:45,7:00,7:15,7:30,7:45,8:00,8:15,8:30,8:45,9:00,9:15,9:30,9:45,10:00,10:15,10:30,10:45,11:00,11:15,11:30,11:45,12:00,12:15,12:30,12:45,13:00,13:15,13:30,13:45,14:00,14:15,14:30,14:45,15:00,15:15,15:30,15:45,16:00,16:15,16:30,16:45,17:00,17:15,17:30,17:45,18:00,18:15,18:30,18:45,19:00,19:15,19:30,19:45,20:00,20:15,20:30,20:45,21:00,21:15,21:30,21:45,22:00,22:15,22:30,22:45,23:00,23:15,23:30,23:45,0:00
5001,5001,KWH,R,05/20/2018,A6,722000,100.0,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000200,0.022600,0.058100,0.100500,0.148500,0.251400,0.295800,0.359500,0.321400,0.365300,0.509800,0.571900,0.734700,1.121900,1.312700,1.358400,1.573900,1.270300,1.512500,1.359400,1.735500,1.759900,1.806400,1.501400,1.343900,1.396900,1.660400,1.924500,2.074300,2.037100,1.409000,1.371600,1.646600,1.591100,1.674500,1.751400,1.366200,1.404300,1.449400,1.405700,1.197900,0.679400,0.793800,0.772400,0.768200,0.969800,0.967400,0.833900,0.623500,0.474100,0.446600,0.368700,0.233500,0.133600,0.043800,0.011100,0.000300,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
```

The first handful of lines of the stored file look like:

```
----------------------------434117419534676393692068
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

SPID,SA_ID,UOM,DIR,DATE,RS,NAICS,APCT,0:15,0:30,0:45,1:00,1:15,1:30,1:45,2:00,2:15,2:30,2:45,3:00,3:15,3:30,3:45,4:00,4:15,4:30,4:45,5:00,5:15,5:30,5:45,6:00,6:15,6:30,6:45,7:00,7:15,7:30,7:45,8:00,8:15,8:30,8:45,9:00,9:15,9:30,9:45,10:00,10:15,10:30,10:45,11:00,11:15,11:30,11:45,12:00,12:15,12:30,12:45,13:00,13:15,13:30,13:45,14:00,14:15,14:30,14:45,15:00,15:15,15:30,15:45,16:00,16:15,16:30,16:45,17:00,17:15,17:30,17:45,18:00,18:15,18:30,18:45,19:00,19:15,19:30,19:45,20:00,20:15,20:30,20:45,21:00,21:15,21:30,21:45,22:00,22:15,22:30,22:45,23:00,23:15,23:30,23:45,0:00
5001,5001,KWH,R,05/20/2018,A6,722000,100.0,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000200,0.022600,0.058100,0.100500,0.148500,0.251400,0.295800,0.359500,0.321400,0.365300,0.509800,0.571900,0.734700,1.121900,1.312700,1.358400,1.573900,1.270300,1.512500,1.359400,1.735500,1.759900,1.806400,1.501400,1.343900,1.396900,1.660400,1.924500,2.074300,2.037100,1.409000,1.371600,1.646600,1.591100,1.674500,1.751400,1.366200,1.404300,1.449400,1.405700,1.197900,0.679400,0.793800,0.772400,0.768200,0.969800,0.967400,0.833900,0.623500,0.474100,0.446600,0.368700,0.233500,0.133600,0.043800,0.011100,0.000300,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
```

And the last couple of lines of the stored file look like this.

```
5090,5090,KWH,D,11/04/2018,A6,713910,104.2,0.333000,0.319000,0.332000,0.309000,0.326500,0.321000,0.322500,0.320000,0.296000,0.322000,0.323000,0.334000,0.321000,0.334000,8.098000,7.043000,1.422000,0.322000,0.323000,0.335000,0.322000,0.322000,0.322000,0.334000,0.336000,0.340000,0.392000,0.584000,0.200000,0.054000,0.176000,0.156000,0.090000,0.000000,0.002000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.002000,0.001000,0.009000,0.014000,0.020000,0.032000,0.054000,0.055000,0.086000,0.127000,0.151000,0.168000,0.220000,0.245000,0.299000,0.282000,0.317000,0.328000,0.314000,0.327000,0.315000,0.328000,0.316000,0.328000,0.318000,0.323000,0.328000,0.319000,0.327000,0.325000,0.320000,0.332000,0.319000,4.420000,3.531000,2.584000,0.458000,1.001000,0.263000,0.263000,0.261000,0.260000,0.258000

----------------------------434117419534676393692068--
```

Is there a way to save the file or access the file in its original format minus the headers and footers? Thanks!

Comment: See the note in the docs section you link to: "For web-based uploads, or for native clients with multipart upload support, you should use the MultiPartParser instead". That's the case here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for helping me understand that clause!